# Trying to copy all of one HashMap's content into a blank HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Superstore class, with two `HashMaps`. One called `storeDetails`, and one that is `customerDetails`.

The `storeDetails` `HashMap` stores `<String, StoreDetails>`.

I have an inherited class called `Store` also.

In my GUI, i've created an instance of the `Store` class and added items into the `storeDetails` `HashMap`. I then create an instance of the `SuperStore` class, and wanting to copy all of the contents over to the blank `HashMap`. I try this by doing:

```
SuperStore superstr = new SuperStore()
Store store = new Store();


// Methods to add in items to the SuperStore HashMap.


superstr.storeDetails.putAll(store.scanned);
```

When printing out the `HashMap`s, the original one prints out the contents but the second one does not. Why is this?

Comment: Please give us a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `putAll`, can you make use of constructor and copy it? Like this:

```
Map blankMap = new HashMap (storeDetails);
```

Comment: Why should the OP change to this code? Are you just hoping this will work when the other code doesn't? Can you even explain *why* `putAll` has failed? To me, it seems likely something else is at fault here and thus this answer is just some guesswork. Have a downvote.

Comment: Of course, this is one of the [documented constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) after all.

Comment: It was because i was trying to put the blank HashMap into the filled HashMap. Should've noticed that ;D

Comment: No, Duncan, stop feeling self-conscious :)

Comment: @james11 Please post an answer to that effect (or delete your question).